# How to save Google play subscription purchase token

Tags: node.js, mongodb, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-developer-api

I am using `NodeJs` and `MongoDB` on the backend and I need to validate the subscription plan after a user has purchased it, for that I have an API that uses `googleapis` package to validate and return the state of the subscription based on token received in the request body. According to the response I update the user.

Additionally, I have specific API routes that should only be accessible to premium users. To ensure that a user has an active subscription, I need to validate the JWT token and check if the user has not canceled their subscription. Therefore, I plan to store the JWT token in the user's collection.

However, I'm concerned about the security implications if a token is stolen. I want to prevent another user from using a stolen token to make their account appear as premium. I've considered a possible solution, but I'm unsure if it is the best approach:

- Adding an index to make each token unique for every user. The problem with this solution is that I would need to store the token as is, without hashing, which raises security concerns.
  I would appreciate any suggestions or improvements on how to handle this situation securely.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think JWT should be one time for user. you can generate random key for each subscribed users or other thing. I think storing JWT is not good idea.

anyway you can save your subscribed keys in your database. but I think it should be encrypt by your one single security key. that key can store in vault service like azure key vault.